# edit/done button, change done button background color

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, interface-builder, uinavigationbar

I have a UITableView with a navigation bar on the top. I changed the style of the navigation bar to **Black Opaque** to go with my theme.

I added an edit button as well using the below line of code

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
```

All is fine so far, the edit button also appears in the balck opaque style.

however the done button appears in the default blue theme. Am i missing some simple thing? How should i change it?

Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

The done button is always blue on a UIBlackBarStyle Navigation bar, but will adjust its color if you use the tintColor property of the navigationBar to color it in your chose of colors. I haven't tried it, but an idea would be to set

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

this should give you a Black navigation bar with a black done Button.

However, for consistency reasons you can not directly set your custom background color on the done button.

Comment: Is it purposefully left to blue color, to catch the attention of the users so that they dont forget to press "Done" after editing? (if so i do not want to change that). :)

Comment: Yes exactly, UIBarButtonItem has a style property and one of the styles is UIBarButtonItemStyleDone which provokes the "done" button like style. This style is always more pronounced than UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered (which is what all other navigation bar items usually use) for the reason you named.